# What makes the entire script block disabled?

Tags: javascript

When I check this code in Firebug, the entire block is disabled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var usercount = 0;
var nbw = '';
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.alphabet').each(function () {
        _$this = $(this);
        nbw = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=CountUsersByLetter&returnformat=json",
            data: "nbw=" + nbw,
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                usercount = parseInt(response.substring(0, 10));
                $(_$this.target).attr('title', usercount);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('errorThrown');
            }
        });
    });
    $('.StartOver').live('click', function () {
        var ReInitAnswer = confirm('Are you sure you want TO DELETE ALL temp dupe records AND start over FROM SCRATCH? \nIt may take a couple OF hours.');
        if (ReInitAnswer) {
            // submit the form TO BEGIN re-creating the temp table
            document.forms["dupeIndivs"].submit();
            //return true; 
        } ELSE {
            alert('canceled');
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('.notdupe').live('click', function (e) {
        alert("indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked"));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=SetNotDupe",
            data: "indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked"),
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error alert(errorThrown); 
            }
        });
    });
    $('.alphabet').live('click', function (l) {
        SelectedLetter = $(l.target).val();
        $(".alphabet").each(function (i) {
            var CheckLetter = $(this).val();
            if (CheckLetter == SelectedLetter) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
                $('.NameBeginsWith').val(SelectedLetter);
            } ELSE {
                $(this).css("background-color", "");
            }
        });
        $('.Reinit').attr('value', SelectedLetter);
        $('.Reinit').trigger('click');
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "disabled"?

Comment: Each line has to be prefixed by four spaces. The block itself has to be prefixed by an empty line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have to replace all uppercase `ELSE` with `else` (JavaScript is case-sensitive).
- Add the closing brace and parenthesis at the end of the code, to finish the `$(document).ready(function(){` block.

Working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var usercount = 0;
    var nbw = '';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.alphabet').each(function () {
            _$this = $(this);
            nbw = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=CountUsersByLetter&returnformat=json",
                data: "nbw=" + nbw,
                datatype: "html",
                success: function (response) {
                    usercount = parseInt(response.substring(0, 10));
                    $(_$this.target).attr('title', usercount);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('errorThrown');
                }
            });
        });
        $('.StartOver').live('click', function () {
            var ReInitAnswer = confirm('Are you sure you want TO DELETE ALL temp dupe records AND start over FROM SCRATCH? \nIt may take a couple OF hours.');
            if (ReInitAnswer) {
                // submit the form TO BEGIN re-creating the temp table
                document.forms["dupeIndivs"].submit();
                //return true; 
            } else { // <------------------------------------ ELSE > else
                alert('canceled');
                return false;
            }
        });
        $('.notdupe').live('click', function (e) {
            alert("indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked"));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=SetNotDupe",
                data: "indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked"),
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // show error alert(errorThrown); 
                }
            });
        });
        $('.alphabet').live('click', function (l) {
            SelectedLetter = $(l.target).val();
            $(".alphabet").each(function (i) {
                var CheckLetter = $(this).val();
                if (CheckLetter == SelectedLetter) {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
                    $('.NameBeginsWith').val(SelectedLetter);
                } else { // <------------------------------------ ELSE > else
                    $(this).css("background-color", "");
                }
            });
            $('.Reinit').attr('value', SelectedLetter);
            $('.Reinit').trigger('click');
        });
    }); // <---------------------------------------------------- Added });
</script>
```

Comment: That was it. I just figured it out.  The capped ELSE comes from using "format source" tool in eclipse. Very strange that they would do that. Once again, Many thanks. I'm closing the door on my way out. Someone needs to tell Chris Kempen he's part of the problem, not the solution.